# Executing Powershell script via azure functions

Tags: powershell, azure, office365, azure-functions

I have got a typical scenario to execute a powershell script via the azure functions and get the data from office 365 API . I am very new to the cloud technology and would like any help that can guide me progressing further.

Comment: Thanks foe replying. The scenario is, I want to use a serverless architecture to retrieve data from O-365 Api using Azure functions. So lets, say I have a powershell command 'Get-MsolUser' which gets some data from the O-365 Rest Api.  I know that powershell loads the O-365 module to execute the commands related to the O-365. However, if I want to get it done thru Azure functions, so that I just call the Azure Function Api from my c# code and the Azure functions does the work of executing the Powershell command for invoking the 'Get-MsolUser', how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use powershell to interact with O365's REST api.

Here is the documentation on powershell's [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) and [O365's API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog).

Azure functions can be written in powershell so you can write this entirely as a function if you want to.

I hope this gets you on the right track!

Edit:

In C# you would do an HTTP post with Json to the Azure Function URL (Which would trigger the function) and your Azure Function would look something like this:

```
$requestBody = Get-Content $Env:req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json #This pulls in your json from your request and converts it to a PSCustomObject

if ($requestbody.name -eq "run") #Which can be refrenced by key/value
{

    $something = Get-MsolUser #Whatever paramters here
    #Put whatever you want to do with the info down here

}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Thanks foe replying. The scenario is, I want to use a serverless architecture to retrieve data from O-365 Api using Azure functions. So lets, say I have a powershell command 'Get-MsolUser' which gets some data from the O-365 Rest Api. I know that powershell loads the O-365 module to execute the commands related to the O-365. However, if I want to get it done thru Azure functions, so that I just call the Azure Function Api from my c# code and the Azure functions does the work of executing the Powershell command for invoking the 'Get-MsolUser', how to achieve that?

Comment: I updated my answer based off of the information you provided in your comment.